# Display certain button text if no file chosen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an image container and a form that changes the photo. The icon opens file browser, and Change button submits the photo and updates it.

[image]

I would like to display another text instead of "Change" if there is no file selected, like "Select a file", and after a file has been selected, to change button text to "Change".

Also, I'm using Material UI Button.

Here is my form code:

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
  <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> Change
    </Button>
</div>
  </form>
```

And here are my handle functions:

```
const [photo, setPhoto] = React.useState(0);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("type", value);
formData.append("photo", photo);

axios.post("/user/update_orar", formData, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});
};

const handlePhoto = (e) => {
  setPhoto(e.target.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: disabling button if no file was selected would work fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you are looking for

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
  <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> 
 {photo === 0 ? "any other text" : "Change"}
    </Button>
</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: for disabling button you can use this "disabled={photo === 0}" property inside button if no file is selected

Answer (score 1):

You have several approaches here. You can just set the text using a ternary expression

```html
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
  <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> {photo? "Change": "Select a file"}
    </Button>
</div>
  </form>
```

You can render different buttons based on the value of the photo state

```html
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
  { photo? <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> Change
    </Button>: <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> Select a file
    </Button>}
</div>
  </form>
```

or you can create a variable and assign a button based on your photo state

```html
const button = photo? <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> Change
    </Button>: <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="small"> Select a file
    </Button>

return 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
  {button}
</div>
  </form>
```

the fist approach is the simpler one, but the other two can be helpful if you want to show buttons with different styles or different onClick handlers